# How can I get path of user.config from another assambly?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, properties.settings, user-config

I would like to have only one configuration file for all assemblies that are in my solution. So what is the best way to get the path of `user.config` from an other assembly?

Comment: You could [add a link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/04/02/linked-files-in-visual-studio-solutions.aspx) to the config file you want to use.

Comment: Already did that, but this generates a seperate user.config in a different folder at runtime.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant that you only wanted one user.config file *at build time*. I didn't realize you wanted one config file at run time as well. Then yes, you'll have to do something like David suggested below.

Answer (score 0):

user.config is nothing but a xml file. You can read it with XmlDocument then.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("user.config");

XmlElement element = doc.DocumentElement;

XmlAttributeCollection attr_coll = myElement.Attributes;

for (int i = 0; i < attr_coll.Count; i++)
{
    string attr_name = attr_coll[i].Name;
}
```

Comment: but how do I get the correct location of the user.config then?

Comment: you don't know the location of user.config?

Comment: How would I know since its something like: C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\%appname%\%appname%.exe_Url_0s1u3ca1jts0vu5qozcghkp3j4rzk3l2\%version%\ ?

Comment: so you might refine your question as: how do I get the path of user.config.

Comment: Hi @christophrus . Have you found an answer to your question? I'm trying to retrieve the path to user.config from different assembly as well. Thank you!